# Create working copy from git bare repository

Tags: git

I understood, that a bare repository is for sharing among different developers or machines. Is it possible to create a working copy from a bare repository, e.g. a new developer joins a project?

Comment: The new developer would clone the repo.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: the new developer is cloning the bare repository?

Answer (score 1):

The point of a bare repository is that there is no working copy -- this makes certain things with pushing easier. Every developer clones the repository, pulls changes from it and pushes his change there.

The whole point of systems like Git is that the developers don't share a single resource on disk, but rather can modify their personal copies at will and still effectively share their changes with each other.